# How do I find working examples of Cocoa/Carbon API?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos-carbon

I find it hard to find some working examples of Cocoa/Carbon framework functions, whereas there are well documented function prototypes from Apple.

For example, **LSOpenItemsWithRole** function has well defined [prototype](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/LaunchServicesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/LSOpenItemsWithRole), but I guess some examples would be a great help for a mac programming beginners like me.

How can I find some working examples for Cocoa/Carbon API? Doesn't Apple provide that? MSDN has good working examples, I expect similar thing from Apple.

Comment: LSOpenItemsWithRole is not a Cocoa API, it is a Carbon API.

Comment: @dreamlax : Thanks for pointing it out, I just wanted to know how to get some working examples.

Comment: @dreamlax: Actually, I don't think LSOpenItemsWithRole is considered Carbon; at least, it's not in the Carbon framework, it's in CoreServices.  Not all APIs that are in C rather than Objective-C are Carbon.

Comment: @JWWalker: It's in the Carbon documentation section; I know not all C frameworks belong under Carbon. In this particular case I noticed that the OP was asking a question only about Cocoa (before the edit) but referenced the non-Cocoa function, which I figured might have been part of the problem. I saw that the URL contained Carbon and thought I would point it out. It's not an API that I use so I didn't exactly know where it belonged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find some sample code on Apple's developer site, and some of it can also be found within the Xcode documentation viewer.  In fact in some cases, but probably not enough, you'll see links to sample code right at the bottom of the API documentation.